# Trigger event for UI indirectly

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm looking for a way to trigger / "redirect" an event from one element to another. How can this be done or is it possible at all? To be clear: I'm **not** searching for a way to directly call an event function, instead I want the browser to execute it itself with all UI aftereffects which would normally occur if a mouse event would happen directly on the actual element. Similar to the behaviour of an `<label>` element for a checkbox.

Example: I have a DIV with a `:hover` CSS pseudo-class and I have a second DIV. Both DIVs are not nested. If the mouse is hovered over the second DIV, I want the browser to act like the mouse is hovered over the first DIV, so it would load the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class for it of the first DIV. But I don't want to create an explicit CSS name for it - I want the browser to use `:hover` and other CSS pseudo-classes.

**Example**

CSS

```
#div1 {
    background: green;
}

#div1:hover {
    background: red;
}

#div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="div1">Hello</div>
<div id="div2">world</div>
```

No jQuery, please. Only plain vanilla JavaScript.

Edit:
Using `dispatchEvent` doesn't trigger the UI (CSS pseudo-classes, like `:hover`). Example (sorry for one-liner):

```
<div id="div2" onmouseover="var e=document.getElementById('div1'); var evt = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {'view': window,'bubbles': true,'cancelable': true}); e.dispatchEvent(evt);">world</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you just change the element ID or class?

Comment: It's not about using foreign CSS classes. I want to "trigger" them. Similar to a `<label>` element that changes the UI appearance of a checkbox remotely.

Comment: You want to call different event when one event gets triggered?

Comment: Kind of, but I don't want to "call" an event function directly, I want the browser to execute the event itself. Again: It is not directly about events. I'm interested in "triggering" the UI effects. I gave you an example with `<label>` element and a checkbox or radiobutton. If you move your mouse over the label, the checkbox will change it's appearance. I would like to know, if something like this is possible for CSS pseudo-classes like `:hover`. If the cursor is moved over the second DIV, the first DIV should change it's background to red, like if the cursor was moved over the first DIV.

Comment: As far as am aware, it is not yet possible to select a previous or parent element using `css`, see [Why we don't have a parent selector](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors). Is requirement to achieve expected result using `css` alone?

Comment: @guest271314 Imagine I would like to write my own `<label>` element (just as an example). I'm not talking about nested elements. Please see my code in my question.

Comment: @user25163 Why do you not use `<label>` elements? How is `css` `:hover` pseudo element related to Question and requirement?

Comment: Because a `<label>` element does not tell the browser to load the `:hover` style of the other element (at least not for DIVs).

Comment: It is not possible to select a previous element using `css`. _"Because a `<label>` element does not tell the browser to load the `:hover`style "_ What do you mean by "tell the browser"?

Comment: Hmm... I think you don't understand me. I have no nested elements. And it doesn't matter if the other element is before or after the current element (or maybe I don't understand you). There are no *previous* elements. We could switch both DIVs in my example. My question is not about pure-CSS. I want to tell the browser through JavaScript to load the `:hover` style of the *foreign* element.

Comment: What do you mean by "foreign element"? _"There are no `previous` elements."_ , _"If the mouse is hovered over the second DIV, I want the browser to act like the mouse is hovered over the first DIV, so it would load the :hover CSS pseudo-class for it of the first DIV."_ First `div` is previous element sibling of second `div`. `css` does not provide a means to select a previous element sibling. Also, the current `css` should not allow another element other than `#div1` to render `:hover`, as `id` of element in `document` should be unique. Are you trying to achieve requirement using `javascript`?

Answer (score 2):

Now I'm pretty sure you want to dispatch a event in JavaScript.

It's pretty simple. You can dispatch a event by using this.

```
elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

where elem is the target element.

You can have a look at [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

This is a code snippet I copied from the Mozilla docs. It dispatches a `MouseClick` Event.

```
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('checkbox'); 
  var cancelled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (cancelled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert("cancelled");
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert("not cancelled");
  }
}
```

and this is for MouseOver event.

```
object.addEventListener("mouseover", myScript);
```

Check out [W3CSchool doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't trigger the CSS pseudo-classes, like `:hover`. I tried it with `MouseEvent` and the event names `mouseover`, `mouseenter` and `mousemove`, but none of them triggered the UI (CSS). They trigger the associated event functions, but like I said, this is not what I'm looking for. I would like to try to dispatch `UIEvent` or `FocusEvent`, but I don't know how to create them (or to be precise: which event names to give them ("mouseover"?).

Comment: You need to pass a Event object. Not string.

Comment: I know. I'm talking about the constructor of `MouseEvent`. It requires the first param to be a string for the event name. I saw and tested the example. But I want to trigger the browser to use `:hover`, so the event name would (I think) be something like `mouseover` but not `click`. Imagine I would like to write my own `<label>` element. I guess this is not widely used or needed so there is probably no way to do this.

Comment: it is "mouseover" that example is for "click". I directly copied it from Mozilla docs.

Comment: I know. ;-) But neither of them work. Please test it with the code from my example.

Comment: Turns out, you cannot do that for `:hover`. Check out this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover

Comment: Thank you. This was the answer I was looking for. It does not solve my problem, because what I want to achieve does not seem to be possible. The sentense in the other answert *"You have to add a class and add/remove that on the mouseover/mouseout events manually."* says it. It's exactly what I feared to have to do: To create a separate CSS class name for the `:hover` pseudo-class, which makes it less modular (I don't want to modify existing CSS classes, since some are not mine). If you write this and the link to your answer, I will mark it as solved. Thanks. :-)