# Adding the :hover pseudoclass

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Is there any way to programmatically have D3 add a ":hover" to a selection?  If not, how can I do this using straight JavaScript?

Comment: Did you look in the D3 docs? What have you tried? etc. etc. You have enough rep to know better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I simulate a mouseover in pure JavaScript that activates the CSS ":hover"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover)

Comment: @RandyCasburn, there was nothing to try as it's not possible in JS, as the answers below show.  D3 documentation would not help as this is not specific to D3.  Rep has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't programmatically add `:hover` from JavaScript (or D3). I'd recommend using a CSS class with the same styling rules:

```
#foo:hover, #foo.selected { ... }
```

And then add the `.selected` class from D3.

(See: [How do I simulate a mouseover in pure JavaScript that activates the CSS ":hover"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover) )

Answer (score 0):

As already explained by cdrini, it is not exactly possible to accomplish this by JavaScript.

Instead, you can use this code to add a class to an element on hover:

```
element.onmouseover = function(){ this.classList.add('foo'); };
element.onmouseout = function(){ this.classList.remove('foo'); };
```