# JS - mouseover and mouseout events are inconstant

Tags: javascript, events

HTML

```
<a class="level-item like-icon">
    <div class="icon is-medium">
        <i class="far fa-heart" onmouseover="change(true)" onmouseout="change(false)"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

JS

```
change = (state) => {
    state
        ? event.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-prefix', 'fas')
        : event.currentTarget.setAttribute('data-prefix', 'far');
};
```

Goal:
To change icon (class, or in this case, attribute) when someone hovers over the icon and revert it back when the user hovers out of it. The above code seems to work but there are a couple issues. 1) It fires way to many times when I hover over it and 2) Many times, it doesn't change the attribute back to "far" (state = false). I tried attaching those events to `<a>` instead of `<li>` but the issues persist.

p.s. NOT using JQUERY

Comment: how is changing the data-prefix supposed to edit the class name?

Comment: `event.currentTarget` "always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached" [@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).  You are not setting eventListeners and assigning handlers but calling a function directly from the HTML Element `onmouse?over/on` attribute.  Therefore, there's no `event` to find the `currentTarget` of.

Comment: @Jhecht I was originally going to update the class name but since I'm using font-awesome svg icons here, the class name is actually the value of data-prefix attrib so going with that.

BrianPeacock trying eventListener way now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 7 'onmouse...' events...

```
onmousedown, 
onmouseenter, 
onmouseleave, 
onmousemove, 
onmouseout, 
onmouseover, 
onmouseup
```

... so it is important to use the right one for the job.

In the example clicking and mouse movement within the Element doesn't apply - all we want is a function to be called once when the mouse **enters** and the element and once agian when the mouse **leaves**.  Therefore...

```
<!-- HTML -->

<a class="level-item like-icon">
    <div class="icon is-medium">
        <i class="far fa-heart" 
           onmouseenter="change(this)"
           onmouseleave="change(this)"></i>
    </div>
</a>
```

So here it seems sensible to use the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` attributes to call the `change()` function, and in this case to passes the HTML Element under the mouse as an argument via the `this` keywords.

Now the function can scrutinize the element and check if it has the desired and required 'data-prefix' attribute, and if so what that attribute is set to.  We can then use this condition to set/reset the 'data-prefix' attribute's value...

```
/* JavaScript */

change = (elem) => {
    // does the Element have a 'data-prefix' attribute
    // and what is it set to?
    let isSet = elem.hasAttribute("data-prefix") && (
        "far" === elem.getAttribute("data-prefix")
    );
    elem.setAttribute("data-prefix", (isSet ? "fas" : "far"));
}
```

However, as has already been mentioned using the `Element.addEventListener()` method is more robust and flexible than relying on HTML attributes like `onmouse...`.

Comment: Thanks for the (detailed) explanation and a solution. Can you please take a look at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOLrjq and see what I'm doing wrong (event listener approach)?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this one ?

Here i adding and removing a class `hover`, but ti also may be any attribute or something else

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  let hovered = document.querySelector('.hover');
  if (e.target === hovered) return;
  if (hovered) { 
    console.log('mouse out from', hovered);
    hovered.classList.remove('hover');
  }
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('icon')) 
    return;
  e.target.classList.add('hover');
  console.log('mouse over on', e.target)
})
```

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 100ms;
  border: solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.hover {
   color: red;
   border-radius: 30%;
   transform: rotate(10deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">1</div>
<div class="icon">2</div>
<div class="icon">3</div>
<div class="icon">4</div>
<div class="icon">5</div>
<div class="icon">6</div>
<div class="icon">7</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting approach. I'll try it out and see how it works out with my scenario.

Comment: @007 i was added console log recenly to show where actions is happen

Comment: Just tried it on my. It fires event as long as the mouse is moving on the screen. Not sure if this will be a viable solution. It seems like because the eventlistener is created at the window level, it's firing everytime the mouse moves on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a duplicate of [How do I simulate a mouseover in pure JavaScript that activates the CSS ":hover"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover)

It's not ideal to deal with mouseover in pure JS, but here is a working example (insipired by an answer to the post I linked).

```js
var element = document.getElementById('hoverIcon');
element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  console.log('Mouse over, set Font Awesome class here');
});

element.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  console.log('Mouse out, remove Font Awesome class here');
});

var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
});
```

```html
<a class="level-item like-icon">
    <div class="icon is-medium">
        <i id="hoverIcon" class="far fa-heart">ICON</i>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Interesting. I see that you're targeting by ID. I've many of these "<a...>" elements and it should only fire the action for the one that's hovered over. Is there a way to manage that?

Comment: @007 I posted a second answer answering this, the action triggered is different for each of the two icons, if you have any issue adapting it to what you are trying to implement let me know

Comment: @007 this is my second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55553658/4463734

Answer (score 1):

Here is a second version of my initial answer, this time with multiple elements.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("hover-icon");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
 element = elements[i];
  element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(data) {
   console.log('Mouse over, set Font Awesome of ID ' + data.originalTarget.id + " here");
});

element.addEventListener('mouseout', function(data) {
  console.log('Mouse out, remove Font Awesome of ID ' + data.originalTarget.id  + " here");
});
} 

var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
});
```

```html
<a class="level-item like-icon">
    <div class="icon is-medium">
        <i id="hoverIcon1" class="hover-icon far fa-heart">ICON1</i>
        <i id="hoverIcon2" class="hover-icon far fa-heart">ICON2</i>
    </div>
</a>
```