# Mock hover state in Storybook?

Tags: storybook

I have a hover style in my component:

```
const style = css`
  color: blue;

  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
`;
```

Can you mock this in Storybook so that it can be shown without having to manually hover over the component?

Comment: Since StoryBook is just HTML, I think your answer will be about the same as this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226753

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in Storybook you need to show the component hover appearance, rather than correctly simulate the hover related stuff,

**the first** option is to add a css class with the same style as *:hover* :

```
// scss
.component {
  &:hover, &.__hover {
    color: red;
  }
}

// JSX (story)
const ComponentWithHover = () => <Component className="component __hover">Component with hover</Component>
```

**the second** one is to use [this addon](https://github.com/Ergosign/storybook-addon-pseudo-states).

Answer (score 1):

For people discovering this question from the internet, Chromatic has provided a Storybook add-on to simulate states in components.

https://github.com/chromaui/storybook-addon-pseudo-states