# Add hover state in StoryBook for Button

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover, storybook

How can I add a hover state to my button storybook function?

I can add the button to my Storybook docs, like this:

```
import ButtonClose from './ButtonClose';

const StoryMeta = {
  title: `Components/Button/ButtonClose`,
  component: ButtonClose,
};

export default StoryMeta;

const Template = (args) => <ButtonClose {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to activate the hover state of my button, which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import SvgIcons from '../SvgIcons';

const ButtonClose = ({ onClick, className }) => (
  <IconButton
    sx={{
      width: '40px',
      height: '40px',
      '&:hover': {
        bgcolor: palette.primary.dark,
    }}
    onClick={onClick}
    className={className}
  >
    <SvgIcons icon="close-button" />
  </IconButton>
);

export default ButtonClose;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mock hover state in Storybook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043424/mock-hover-state-in-storybook)

Comment: Unfortunately no :(. I don't know how I could implement this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try onMouseEnrer event in your button
You can define a boolean state and by
onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave change the value of your state
Then use conditional operation for bgColor.
For example :
const [isHover,setIsHover] = useState(false)

And in button :

```
<IconButton
   onMouseEnter={()=>setIsHover(true)}
   onMouseLeave={()=>setIsHover(false)}
   sx={{
        width: '40px',
        height: '40px',
        bgColor:(theme)=>isHover?        theme.palette.primary.dark:theme.palette.primary.light
  }}
 >
```