# How to mouse hover and click Anchors on a webpage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I am stuck at maneuvering this webpage using JavaScript. The page has a menu 'button', which can be clicked and then a menu rolls down on left side of the page. However, none of the menu items are buttons, they all are some sort of text anchors(internet research). I tried sending clicks to them but nothing really happens. Using console on Google Chrome I was able to find their index but the activation/ click never happens.
I this case I am trying to go in this direction *Menu -> Utilities -> Cube -> Inquiry*. Clicking Inquiry should open a page in the same window. But doing following I can only go as far as getting the Menu button clicked. Any ideas what I should try here? I am using Power Automate Desktop - un JavaScript function on web page Action.
NOTE: id (ext-gen1234)is dynamic, it sort of changes and is not fixed.

Html:

```HTML
<div class="x-layer x-menu x-menu-bpcloadmenu" id="ext-gen1100" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: auto; max-height: 846px;">
   <a class="x-menu-focus" href="#" onclick="return false;" tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen1102"></a>
   <ul class="x-menu-list" id="ext-gen1103" style="max-height: 816px;">
      <li class="x-menu-list-item " id="ext-gen1173">
         <a href="#" class="x-menu-item x-menu-item-arrow" id="ext-gen1174">  
           <img src="../resources/images/default/s.gif" class="x-menu-item-icon ">
            Utilities
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What I have tried to do in Power Automate Desktop (Run JavaScript function on web page)

```
function ExecuteScript() { 
//Menu button click
document.querySelectorAll('button')[0].click();
//Utilities index activation attempt
document.querySelectorAll('a')[24].click();
//Cube index activation attempt
document.querySelectorAll('a')[80].click();
//Inquiry index activation attempt
document.querySelectorAll('a')[75].click();
}
```

Only 1st step clicks the Menu button, rest seem to be doing nothing.

Comment: `href="#"` is an empty hash,  and doesn't be usable for anything

Comment: Yes, I could not pull off a link from it at all, and these menu items react to hover and fold open next set of menu items to choose from.

Comment: Please read carefully :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  and this point => https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some additional research, turns out the html is responsive to mouse hover to open up menu for next 'step'.
First click open the menu button:

```
function ExecuteScript() {

 document.querySelectorAll(\'button\')[0].click();

}
```

Added all anchors to a list “Current Anchor”, then used For Each loop in the PAD to run the below JavaScript.

```
 function ExecuteScript() { 
  //determine the xpath of the Anchor using string search method
  var xpath = "//a[text()='%CurrentAnchor%']";
  var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  //check if the Anchor is found and look for its id
  if (matchingElement) {
       // get id of CurrentAnchor (ext-gen1234)
       ID = matchingElement.closest('a').id;
       //define the element found by ID
       var element = document.getElementById(ID);
       //set event listener for mouse hover to the element
       element.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
       console.log('Event triggered');
       });
       //send event of mouse hover
       var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover', {
       'view': window,
       'bubbles': true,
       'cancelable': true
       });
       element.dispatchEvent(event);
       }
}
```

Lastly clicking the button to get to the page I wanted to.

```
function ExecuteScript() { 
 //determine the xpath of the Anchor using string search method
 var xpath = "//a[text()='Inquiries']";
 var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
 //check if the Anchor is found and look for its id
 if (matchingElement) {
       // get id of CurrentAnchor (ext-gen1234)
       ID = matchingElement.closest('a').id;
       //click the element found by ID
       document.getElementById(ID).click();
 }
}
```

Credits:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50206746/17413703
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289196/18392362